# Visual Studio C# and Bunifu UI, can't find on click method

Tags: bunifu

I'm sorry if the title is long, my problem is I added a button (From Bunifu framework) programmatically.

Here is the code:

```
Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton Contact = new Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton();
ContactsBox.Controls.Add(Contact);
```

Tho I need the onClick method, and I do not know how to get it.. Any help?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Forms? Windows Forms? What is this? What have you tried to set up the click event handler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Events To WinForms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929337/adding-events-to-winforms)

Comment: "And now i need to get when it where clicked, but i can't just create a void, can i? "  I am unable to parse this sentence into anything meaningful.

Comment: If by "create a void" you mean "write my own event handler", the answer is "yes".

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour] and take great pains to research your problem(s) as well as explaining your problem when posting.  Based on `create a void` a good book might not be a bad idea either

Comment: "a good book" like?

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Seba4316 various websites have reviews of programming books.  make use of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to answer because the question is poorly worded and I'm not certain this is what you're looking for, but here's how to hook up a `Click` event to a control created in code:

```
var button = new Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton();
button.Click += Button_Click;
```

In Visual studio, after you type the `+=`, pressing `Tab` will create the click event template for you:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you just replace the `throw` line with whatever code you want to execute when your button is clicked.

An instance of the control whose event triggers this method is passed through the `sender` argument. A common way to get the instance inside the event is to check the type and cast it:

```
if(sender is BunifuFlatButton)
{
    var button = (BunifuFlatButton) sender;
    MessageBox.Show($"You clicked the button named '{button.Name}'");
}
```

Comment: Thank you but i need either to get the name of the button from the void..

Comment: @Seba4316 - The button that was clicked is the `sender` argument of the `Button_Click` event handler.  You can get its name by casting `sender` to your button class and checking the `Name` property.

Comment: I found this way too: Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton Contact2 = (sender as Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton); explication: Objectname NewName = (sender as Objectname); and then i done string Name = Contact2.Text;

Comment: Yep, that works too. The only reason I add the `if(sender is BunifuFlatButton)` is that it's possible for other controls to also use this event handler. I know that's unlikely since you're the one writing the code, but it's good practice to not assume. :)