# More efficient way to format several nearly identical functions?

Tags: c#, .net, function, optimization, format

I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to format the following code:

```
    private void nmudc1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(nmudc1);
    }

    private void nmudc1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(nmudc1);
    }

    private void nmudc2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(nmudc2);
    }

    private void nmudc2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(nmudc2);
    }
```

And so on.

I apologize if this has been asked before or elsewhere, and I assume the answer is relatively simple. Unfortunately, I have been unsuccessful in finding a suitable answer thus far.

I have thought about trying to put in in an array, or an object, but I really just have no idea how I would go about doing this to a function like this.

Thank you.

Comment: You have two identical functions? You could delete `nmudc1_Click` and `nmudc2_Click` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create only one event function, And send the sender as parameter to the `SelectAllNumericalUpDownText` function.

Register all events to this function:

```
nmudc1.Click += nmudc_Event;
nmudc1.Enter += nmudc_Event;
nmudc2.Click += nmudc_Event;
nmudc2.Enter += nmudc_Event;
```

Generic implementation to the function:

```
 private void nmudc_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(sender as <TYPE>);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer. I wasn't sure what to register the events to, and this has solved my question completely.

Comment: I glad.  If its good solution please mark the answer as correct.. :) Regardint to register events in generlly, You can read more information in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929337/adding-events-to-winforms?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

Since all event handlers in your code sample have the same method signature, you can simply use the same method to handle all the events:

```
private void NumericUpDown_event(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(sender as NumericUpDown); 
}
```

This is assuming, of course, that your sender object is actually a `NumericUpDown`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following alternative:

```
    private void NumericUpDown_Event(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is <controltype> nump))
           return;

        SelectAllNumericalUpDownText(nump);
    }
```

By this you do not call the method if the sender is not of type < controltype >. Therefor you already used the generic EventArgs class you can subscript the Enter/Click event to this method.