# Connect an event to function from other file of the partial class

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form, named MainForm, which contains a button. I created another file for my form class, and write a few functions for the partial class:

In one file (MainForm.cs):

```
namespace myForm
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        // Some functions...
    }
}
```

In other file (otherFile.cs):

```
namespace myForm
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Some code...
        }
        // Some functions...
    }
}
```

When I try to connect between a button click and the function `button_Click` from the second file, the function doesn't appear.

Is there a way to fix it, without inserting the function manually?

Comment: Make sure the namespaces match.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes They are

Comment: Can you show the code that you have and explain what you have tried?  Also please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example 
I'm sure we'd be glad to help you, it's just a little difficult with nothing to work with.

Comment: @DCCoder I added some code to demonstrate the code I wrote.

Comment: They also must be in the same assembly (exe, dll), i.e., in the same project.

Comment: @Dani This may be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929337/adding-events-to-winforms